# Eclipse Crash on Launch - JVM terminated. Exit code=2

Tags: eclipse, crash, jvm, launch

I will do my best to make my situation as clear as possible. I tried googling the error message, but I haven't found any topic regarding `exit code=2` anywhere. I only found topics regarding different exit codes, and I'm trying to fix my issue following the advice given there - no luck so far. Also I'm a newbie when it comes to any form of Linux (the distribution I'm using is Ubuntu).

### Problem:

My eclipse crashes on launch with following error window popping up:

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=2
/usr/bin/java
-Xms40m
-Xmx384m
-Dorg.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.directory=/usr/share/eclipse/dropins
-jar /usr/lib/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.dist.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash /usr/lib/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.platform_3.8.1.dist/splash.bmp
-launcher /usr/lib/eclipse/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library/usr/lib/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.dist/eclipse_1503.so
-startup /usr/lib/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.dist.jar
--launcher.overrideVmargs
-exitdata 670018
-vm /usr/bin/java
-vmargs
-Xms40m
-Xmx384m
-Dorg.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.directory=/usr/share/eclipse/dropins
-jar /usr/lib/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.dist.jar
```

There is a big posibility that my problem is related to lack of proper Java version installed.

I suspect this because:

I had eclipse running on my pc two days ago. Yesterday I had to use a web-application which required a specific version of JRE installed. Due to my lack of linux knowledge, I spent a few hours removing my current installations of java JREs and JDKs (so I could install the required version) using multiple guides that I found on the internet (some included commands like `sudo apt-get purge java*` and other commands including removing, java and *). Today my Eclipse wont launch.

When I run

```
java -version
```

it says no such file or directory, but the webpages like 
http://www.java.com/en/download/testjava.jsp
http://javatester.org/version.html
do work and say that my java version is

```
Vendor: Oracle Corporation 
Version: Java SE 7 Update 25 
Operating System: Linux 3.5.0-34-generic 
Java Architecture: 64-bit
```

installed using this method:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

Can someone please guide me how to solve this specific problem? Luckly I haven't made any important projects in my Eclipse yet so I don't mind purging the installation if necessary.

To be completely honest the main reason I need Eclipse for is the Remote Server Explorer option, so if anyone knows a good IDE other than Eclipse that can provide just as good Remote Server Explorer it would be a perfect-fast-temporary solution.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error message and solved it by starting eclipse with the -clean parameter. 
To use the clean parameter:
Edit the eclipse.ini file located in your Eclipse install directory and insert -clean as the first line. Once started, remove the -clean parameter in the eclipse.ini file.

It worked for me...

Answer (score 2):

Set\Change your current jdk path in eclipse.ini.

```
-vm
C:\Java\JDK\1.8\bin\javaw.exe
```

Sample Ini file contents:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.100.v20110502
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vm
C:\Java\JDK\1.8\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms40m
-Xmx1024m
```

Answer (score 1):

The following environment variables were removed and the Connect client was able to successfully launch:

_JAVA_OPTIONS
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS
IBM_JAVA_OPTIONS

The operating system environment variables can be found by:

```
From Desktop, right-click on My Computer icon-> Properties -> Advanced.
Click the Environment variables button to remove the before-mentioned system environment variables.
```

Answer (score 1):

In the environment variables check the value of Path variable, it would have reference to the Oracle javapath which would be incorrect java version and may cause the issue. just remove "C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;" from the Path variable and try.

Answer (score -1):

We need to delete all the content in the folder specified in the error msg.Please go through the link below for example [JVM Terminated](http://salesforceglobe4u.blogspot.in/2016/06/jvm-terminatedexit-code2.html)